# Why am I getting an "undefined method" error with my has_one relationship in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods, belongs-to, has-one, database-relations

I have a page that outputs all of the user profiles that exist in the system.  It was working before, I haven't changed anything, and now it is not working.  It is telling me that I have "an undefined method `profile_name' for nil:NilClass", but I refer to profile_name many times elsewhere in the application.  Here is the index view page:

```
<% @profiles.each do |profile| %>
    <%= link_to profile.user.inspect, profile_path(profile.user.profile_name) %><br><br>
<% end %>
```

Here is the profile model:

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
end
```

Here is the user model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :profile
```

Here is the profiles controller:

```
def index
    @profiles = Profile.all
end
```

Also, the profile table in the database has a column user_id.  Plus, I checked my database and all user's have a profile name.  On the profile page, I reference @user.profile.(profile attribute) so I know the has_one/belongs_to relationship is working.  I can't figure out what to do.  Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do all your Profiles have a `user_id` value? You might want to consider doing the following to verify that `user_id` is present for all Profiles:

```
Profile.pluck :user_id
```

I suspect a profile object/record does not have a `user_id` and hence traversing via `profile.user.profile_name` renders the nil class error.

Answer (score 0):

For whatever reason, your `profile.user` is `nil`.  Since `nil` does not have the method `.profile_name` defined, you get your error.

My guess is there's a profile in `@profiles` that does not have `user_id` defined.